# Disable saving history

Tags: r, session, history

Is it possible to disable saving command history / session in R by default ? I really hate those .RData and .RHistory files !!

Comment: Are you using windows/linux/mac?

Comment: If you're using a command line interface, I keep the following alias in my .bash_profile: R64='R64 --no-save --no-restore-data --quiet' -- nice and easy. (Similar for R/R32)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just start up R with `--no-save`. See `R --help`.

Add this to your shortcuts  (in Windows for example this is under "Target" when you right-click on the shortcut and choose properties).

[image]

Comment: Thanks mdsummer! Any idea how to do this with Notepad++? I tried adding the path to npptor.ini (R=C:\...\bin\x64\Rgui.exe) with and without --no-save, but NppToR seems not to find Rgui. It works if I let it to take it from the registry.

Comment: You mean edit a shortcut with a text editor? I don't know anything about Notepad++

Comment: No. It's an external R script editor, which can be used to send scripts to Rgui.

Comment: Ah, I found solution. Write only the home directory to R Home (R=C:\...\R\R-2.15.0) and the command into R cmd line parameters (Rcmdparms=--no-save --no-restore-data --quiet). Thanks guys! This gave me a smoother R experience.

Comment: No, see Project Options under General

Answer (score 25):

If you're using RStudio, you can simply disable in settings.

Go to Tools -> Global options -> General and un-tick always save history.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you are using an R gui, an alternative and quite nice approach, due to Brian Ripley,  ([see here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2001-January/010615.html)), is to put the following lines in  your 'R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site' file:

```
q <- function (save = "no", status = 0, runLast = TRUE)
.Internal(quit(save, status, runLast))
```

One note of caution: this won't work when you invoke R from the command-line. In that case, just use the `--no-save` argument described in @mdsumner answer.

To learn more about 'Rprofile.site', and '.Rprofile' (an optional per-directory config file), see the always useful [`?Startup`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html) help file.

Comment: I use the R gui and I typically exit with command/Q, which creates aa .Rapp.history.  In R preferences I have "Save workspace on exit from R" set to No, but it saves it anyway.

Comment: I tried turning off both "Read history file on startup" and "Save workspace on exit" but that made no difference.  Finally I settled on this: I changed the default history file to include "~/" so it places it in my home directory.  Then at least I only have the one copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

Even more flexible (Windows), add R and RStudio to your right-click menu so you can start in any directory

R-Gui: save the following in a file rguihere.reg, and double-click

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\RGui]
@="R Gui here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\RGui\command]
@="cmd.exe /c \"pushd  %L &&start rgui --no-restore --no-save\""
```

RStudio

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\RStudio]
@="RStudio here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\RStudio\command]
@="cmd.exe /c \"pushd %L &&start C:\\PROGRA~1\\RStudio\\bin\\rstudio.exe\""
```