# Simultaneously inhibit creating .Rhistory and DS_Store

Tags: r, git, macos, github

After switching to a new Mac (macOS Sierra) and re-cloning all of my GitHub repositories, I began to encounter a new problem. Whenever I make changes and save an R script, and run:

```
git status

## Untracked files:
##   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
## .DS_Store
## .Rhistory
```

`.DS_Store` and `.Rhistory` appear.

**Question: Is there a way to stop and/or ignore (e.g. via `.gitignore`, see below) these files when committing R scripts to GitHub?**

I understand similar questions may have been asked, I decided to still raise this question because I really want to make sure that I get the setting right at the first place, especially if others have encountered similar problems before. If you have a way and/or references of how to solve this highly specific problem--which may require a combination of bash Terminal, R, as well as the operating system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest and simplest way is to add `.DS_Store` and `.Rhistory` to your global `gitignore` file.

[Here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#create-a-global-gitignore) is how to do it, in a nutshell: open or create (if doesn't exist yet) `~/.gitignore_global` and add `.DS_Store` and `.Rhistory` on two new lines.

If your repository already includes any unwanted files, use `git rm` to get rid of them ([link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)).

Comment: The global gitignore idea is very convenient. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found several relevant references that can lead to a potential solution:

1. [Mac OS X v10.4 and later: How to prevent .DS_Store file creation over network connections](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht1629), which simply asks user to run the line below in **Terminal** to stop generating `.DS_Store` files:

   defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
2. [r - Disabling saving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098189/disable-saving-history). This earlier post provides instruction on how to disable creation of `.Rhistory` files on Windows.
3. [Remove `.DS_Store` files from a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107701/how-can-i-remove-ds-store-files-from-a-git-repository) using `.gitignore`. I suppose the same could be done to `.Rhistory`

Still, if you have a better solution, please share with the community!