# How to turn off Autosaving workspace in R application of Visual Studio

Tags: r, visual-studio, rtvs

[image]I am working with Visual Studio and don't know how to turn off the Autosaving workspace of R application of Visual Studio even I googled. It made my programming process very slow. I just wonder if anyone can instruct me how to do that?
Thank you very much!

Comment: There's some general advice on how to disable auto-saving in R here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098189/disable-saving-history.  However, I can't figure out where in RTVS you can define the default way to start Rgui.exe