# Can I prevent R from creating .RData files?

Tags: r

I am trying to share some R code with colleagues who don't know R. I have created a batch file so they can just double-click it and run the R script without even opening R. But it creates a `.RData` file.

My question is, can I prevent R from creating the `.RData` file?

I've read here [Disable saving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098189/disable-saving-history) that I could disable it through RStudio global options but my colleagues are installing just R and won't need to ever open it, so I am looking for some kind of solution of the likes of `options(...)` that I can just put in my Rscript, or maybe something that could be speficied in the batch file call.

Comment: When I run `R` from the console, it does not save to the `.Rhistory` file. How are your colleagues using R such that the `.Rhistory` file is being created?

Comment: You should show us a sample script, but it's likely that all you need is `q(save = "no")`.

Comment: @r2evans you're right, sorry. The `.Rhistory` was generated after running it through RStudio. But the `.RData` does appear when executing the batch file to run the script.

Comment: Why not using rmarkdown for that? Since they "don't know R", your colleagues will be happy about your helpful and nicely formatted comments your report will come with.

Comment: How are your colleagues using R? Are they using Rgui/Rterm? Rscript? `R CMD BATCH`? `R --no-save` (suggested by reading `R --help`) should preclude saving the `~/.Rdata` file.

Comment: @jay.sf I'm not actually reporting anything, my script is to update some excel files after doing some calculations in R, so my colleagues don't need to see anything, just double-click and then the excel files are updated. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @r2evans I'm doing it through a batch file with `R CMD BATCH "%file%" NUL`.  Should I just add `--no-save` ?

Comment: @r2evans I'm doing it through a batch file with `R CMD BATCH "%file%" NUL`.  I tried `R --no-save CMD BATCH "%file%" NUL`  but the `.RData` keeps appearing. (`"%file%"` is the Rscript path)

Comment: Try `R` instead of `R CMD BATCH`; the latter does not support `--no-save`. The use of `R` instead of `R CMD BATCH` will require you to handle stdin and stdout/stderr yourself, not sure if that'd be a problem.

Comment: I don't actually know what stdin or stdout/stderr are... Not sure how to do that.

Comment: I figured it out, I was messsing up the order. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

For anyone curious, I figured it out thanks to @r2evans and this post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166211/evitar-que-r-cree-ficheros-r-data-y-r-history.

I just had to add `--no-save` to my batch call like this:

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save "%file%" NUL
```

where `%file%` is the Rscript path. The `NUL` part is so a `.Rout` file won't be created after running the batch file.

Also, doing

```
Rscript.exe "%file%"
```

runs the Rscript and doesn't produce `.RData` or `.Rout` files. The difference is that R messages get printed on the command window as they would in an interactive R session.